# 15.04 to 15.10 upgrade locked up with cryptic screen

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, lockup

Running dual boot Windows with Ubuntu 15.04.

I selected an upgrade to 15.10. The process seemed to run fine except for stopping occasionally to ask me to keep or overwrite certain configuration files (about the meaning of which I had no idea).

I went away when it started applying the upgrade, and returned to see a screen listing a bunch of apparent tasks, some appearing in red to indicate (presumably) a problem. The last item looked successful, but the screen did not change. Finally, I switched power off.  Now I cannot boot Ubuntu at all.

How do I get 15.10 to boot?

Comment: Do you have a backup and do you have a live CD?

Comment: Also please avoid rants...

Comment: Of course I have no backup.  But I can make a live CD.  I used the recovery method to boot and go to root login.  Apparently some boot sequence configuration file got deleted, causing the normal boot to stop with no message on screen.  I launched some disproportionate gui with startx, then ran unity, then rebooted into root terminal and logged in as my user id, then ran startx and unity, and got my unity going.  Apparently all user files are intact.  Now I need to know how to reconstruct the config files so the thing boots properly.

Comment: By the way, Tim, don't misconstrue displeasure with the functionality of the BROKEN UPGRADE or suggestions for specific improvement as a "RANT".  You do NO GOOD by deleting such items.  Developers need to know them.  You just worsen UBUNTU by blocking them.

Comment: I'd really like to know how many other people suffered a similar disaster when upgrading with the normal UBUNTU update mechanism.

Comment: "HOW MANY YEARS MUST USERS TOLERATE THIS kind of ARCANE, CRYPTIC installation?" is a rant, not feedback. On top of that, this site is not Ubuntu. This site is Ask Ubuntu, run by Stack Exchange. In no way would ubuntu be better by you shouting at us on the internet, and it is site policy for them to be removed. Currently there are 100 questions tagged [tag:15.10] and about half of those seem to be update problems, and half 3rd party apps. So not really many.

Comment: When you login to Ubuntu run the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally concluded that the system had completed the UBUNTU 15.10 install, but did not leave the system in a condition where it would boot and load xwindows and the Unity interface.  I rebooted and used the recovery mode at the grub OS Selection screen, went to the root prompt, ran startx and unity, and ended up with a low-res incorrect aspect ratio.

The upgrade failed to keep my /home mountpoint on the drive and partition UBUNTU 15.04 had used (not the boot drive and partition).  I had mistakenly thought the whole idea of setting up a separate /home drive & partition was to facilitate upgrades without disturbing data.  So, I set out to change the /home mount point from the boot partition to the previous /home, and then deleted the existing /home.  That was a big mistake because after that, UNITY menu and dash disappeared, and the gui crashed.

By this time my complaining had gotten me stifled on askubuntu, so I could not ask further help for some days.  In frustration, I simply installed UBUNTU 15.10 Gnome over the top of the existing installation.

Incidentally, I first tried installing from the Live DVD, but the installer did not recognize that I wanted to upgrade, maybe because it detected an existing upgrade.  I wonder why the developers don't put messages on the screen explaining such decisions that will confuse users.

I aborted that install and installed from a distribution on my YUMI Multiboot SanDisk Extreme USB flash drive.  The install went EXTREMELY quickly.

In the process, using the installer's partitioning manager, I set /home to the existing drive and partition the 15.04 installation had used as /home.  When I finished the install, UBUNTU had ignored the mount point and set its own /home folder in the boot drive (an SSD without much space left).  Now I must ask what went wrong and how to do it correctly next time so that the mountpoint STICKS on the existing /home at the non-boot drive and partition.

At least I have a perfectly functioning Gnome UBUNTU 15.10 on my dual boot system.  I only need now to change the /home mountpoint and reinstall all the old apps the new install wiped out.